# Convert html to pdf on the fly using Python and HTMLDOC

Tags: python, django, htmldoc

I built a Django application for a client about a year ago. He has now resold the application to some super secret government agency that they won't even tell me the name of.

Part of the application dynamically generates PDF files using the python library xhtml2pdf (pisa). The Government doesn't like this library, they won't tell me why, they said I have to use [HTMLDOC](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) for pdf generation.

There's not much documentation on this library, but from reading the PHP example, it looks like you can just communicate with it through the shell, so it should work with Python. However, I'm having a hard time passing the html to HTMLDOC. It looks like HTMLDOC will only accept a file, but I really need to pass the html as a string since it's dynamically generated. (Or write the html string to a temporary file and then pass that temporary file to HTMLDOC).

I thought StringIO would work for this, but I'm getting an error. Here's what I have:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html  = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("utf-8"))
    os.putenv("HTMLDOC_NOCGI", "1")

    #this line throws "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"
    htmldoc = subprocess.Popen("htmldoc -t pdf --quiet '%s'" % result, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

    pdf = htmldoc[0]
    result.close()
    return HttpResponse(pdf, mimetype='application/pdf')
```

Any ideas, tips, or help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Stack Trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: (redacted)

Django Version: 1.3 alpha 1 SVN-14921
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'application']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response

  111. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view

  23. return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ascgov/application/views/pdf.py" in application_pdf

  90. 'user':owner})

File "/home/ascgov/application/views/pdf.py" in render_to_pdf

  53. htmldoc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/htmldoc -t pdf --quiet '%s'" % result, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py" in __init__

  633. errread, errwrite)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py" in _execute_child

  1139. raise child_exception

Exception Type: OSError at /pdf/application/feed-filtr/
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify the absolute path to the `htmldoc` executable, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/htmldoc`?

Comment: Good suggestion. Tried it and I'm still getting "[Errno 2] No such file or directory". Thanks though.

Comment: `Errno 2` suggests strongly, that there's no problem on the python side, but on the shell/callout side. (btw, if you want a nice wrapper around `subprocess`, take a look at [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `subprocess.Popen`'s first arg should generally be a list (unless you also pass `shell=True`). The `No such file or directory` is almost certainly caused by the absence of a file named `"htmldoc -t pdf --quiet '...` on the system (it's trying to find and run the program named for the whole string value).

Second, if you give htmldoc some html on its stdin, it'll spit out a pdf on its stdout, thus avoiding the need for a temporary file.

Give this a try (untested):

```
htmldoc = subprocess.Popen(
  ['/usr/bin/htmldoc', '-t', 'pdf', '--webpage', '-'], 
  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
stdout, stderr = htmldoc.communicate(html)
```

NB: substitute `/usr/bin/htmldoc` for the real path to htmldoc on your system.

The `-` argument to the htmldoc program, tells it to read from stdin. You'll pass your html string value (`html`) to htmldoc's `stdin` as an argument to the `htmldoc.communicate` call. The resulting pdf output should be available in `stdout`, and any other messages or stats in `stderr`.

**Edit**: The documentation does seem a bit wonky, but there is quite a bit of it. You might have better luck with the [html in one page](https://www.msweet.org/documentation/project1/HTMLDOC.html) or [pdf](https://www.msweet.org/documentation/project1/HTMLDOC.pdf) versions, or the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/htmldoc.1.html).

Also, be sure to pass a string, or similar, to the stdin of the htmldoc process. Passing a StringIO object directly, as was implied by my previous code snippet, won't work.

Comment: Marty this is a great explanation. Your solution works. I wasn't understanding Popen. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Blergh. What a horrible requirement, and a horrible program.

There doesn't seem to be any way to take the content to be converted as a command-line option. It does seem, though, that it accepts a URL. So, conceivably, you could pass a constructed URL that references a view on the same server, and in that second view output your rendered template which is then picked up by HTMLDOC running from the first view. Just be aware that this won't work with the development server, as it's single-threaded, so the views will be forever waiting for each other.